# React-Native: Download Image and convert it to Base64 Image

Tags: javascript, image, download, react-native

Is there a way to convert an image from an URL (website) and afterwards to convert it to a Base64 Image?

**My goal is it to download an image from website and to store it with AsyncStorage** so that I can access the image without internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use any third party library to do so.

https://github.com/riyadhalnur/node-base64-image